# Does "ng new" downloads packages or gets them from Angular CLI?

Tags: angular, angular-cli

I'm new to angular and cli-related stuff, and wanted to know when creating a new project with `ng new` whether the packages are downloaded online or got form angular cli which is installed globally?

Comment: They are downloaded using npm or yarn.

Comment: No, they're downloaded like a `npm i` (in fact, `npm i` is ran).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Downloaded online from npmjs.com or from a local cache you have for those dependencies on your machine.

Edit: npm is not the only package manager available out there. of course, you can use Yarn or any other registry.

Comment: ```or from a local cache```? How so? (I'm a noob in this, and if you can add this to your answer please).

Comment: NPM caches some of the packages on your machine so you won't have to download them every time. Read more about NPM cache here: https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/cache.html

Comment: Actually I'm a heavy user of pnpm which saved me a lot of disk space. I didn't know about npm caching to save data. I only knew about yarn. Good to know.

Comment: Yarn does that too.